# Pro file settings to create single lib file using qmake

Tags: qmake, shared-libraries

I am using QTCreator to create a library for a project I am working on. So my pro file looks something like:

```
QT       += core
QT       += printsupport
QT       += webkitwidgets
QT       += gui

TARGET = ProjectName
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = lib


SOURCES += \
    #my source files

HEADERS += \
     #my header files
```

It creates the file `libProjectName.so.1.0.0` then proceeds to to create symbolic links to it with the names `libProjectName.so`, `libProjectName.so.1`, and `libProjectName.so.1.0`.

**I really just want `libProjectName.so.1.0.0` to be called `libProjectName.so` and not bother with the symbolic links. Is there a way to configure this in the pro file?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force qmake not to create symbolic links to target when TEMPLATE=lib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074050/how-to-force-qmake-not-to-create-symbolic-links-to-target-when-template-lib)

Comment: @smokris Thanks, my google fu most be getting rusty.